# Why ClearCase Explorer is that ClearQuest Web is not supported UCM integration?

Tags: integration, clearcase, clearquest

I have integration UCM, the problem is that with one specific user when you add new file to source control and connect with CQ record it says:

```
This operation is not yet supported for ClearQuest Web connections.
Please use a ClearQuest native client connection to perform this operation.
```

How to avoid that error message?

Comment: Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I expand my answer below in your new question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/38384504/6309

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the exact version of ClearCase.

CCRC (ClearCase Remote Client, 7.1.X up to 8.0.1) for example, has quite a number of limitation when integrated  ClearQuest ([swg21398642](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21398642)).
If this is CCRC, see "[CCRC supports the UCM integration with ClearQuest](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21221366)"

If it is not CCRC, then check "[Establishing the Rational ClearQuest Web interface](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_bcccq_estbl_web.htm)", which does mention:

> If the Rational® ClearQuest® client is installed on a developer system, it is used by default.
>
> If the Rational ClearQuest client is not installed on a developer system, the Rational ClearQuest Web Interface is the default interface.
>
> To enable a client to use the Rational ClearQuest Web Interface, set the following configuration parameters in the configuration file or the environment variables from the command-line prompt: