# Why ClearQuest and ClearCase 9 are not longer support Native client integration?

Tags: clearcase

When I attempt to get a ClearQuest Record or make a new one using ClearCase version 9, now it tells you that native client is not supported, also crmregister is not allowing you to add databases without an url, is there any way to keep it integrated using native CQ client?

Answer (score 3):

"[About using the LAN ClearCase/WAN ClearQuest UCM integration that utilizes the ClearQuest OSLC REST interface](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21398642)" explaines how ClearCase UCM and ClearQuest record used to communicate up to CC 8.0:

> Previously, the ClearCase UCM/ClearQuest integration required that both ClearCase and ClearQuest be installed on the local machine. This implied that there must be a local ClearQuest database replica available. This also implied that both ClearCase and ClearQuest must be supported on the platform of the local machine.
>
> Now, ClearCase UCM can communicate with ClearQuest through the ClearQuest OSLC REST API, which is installed with ClearQuest Web. Note that the option to continue to use a local ClearQuest client is still available.

If you compare **Using the OSLC REST interface** between [ClearCase 8.0](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.int.doc/topics/ccsumcqint/r_oslc_rest_interface.htm) and [ClearCase 9.0](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.int.doc/topics/ccsumcqint/r_oslc_rest_interface.htm), you will see that, in addition of the support of Native ClearCase clients such as cleartool and ClearCase Explorer, it supports also

> The Change Management Integration (CMI), which supports configuring ClearCase with various task providers, including ClearQuest; refer to [Administering and using CMI task-provider integrations for more information](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_task_provider_integ.htm).

But the point is, the initial local communication (where both ClearCase and ClearQuest are installed on the local machine, with a local ClearQuest database replica available) is not the default one anymore:

> To specify the connection to the ClearQuest OSLC REST API (a web URL connection), use the **`crmregister`** command.
>   By specifying a web URL connection, you configure the integration to use the implementation for all ClearQuest-enabled UCM Projects that use the specified ClearQuest database.
>   **If a web URL connection is not provided, then the assumed configuration is a LAN connection to the ClearQuest native Windows client**.

By default, those products are installed to support CMI only.
See "[Capabilities and limitations of ClearCase UCM integrations with ClearQuest](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21959883)":

> **The Change Management Integration (CMI) architecture was introduced in 2013**.
>   It is a robust implementation in the core of ClearCase that provides a uniform and extensible integration across all ClearCase contexts and both configuration management models.
>
> - CMI supports the GUIs and command line interfaces of CCLC and CCRC.
> - It supports both base ClearCase and UCM. Further, it allows multiple CM systems to be used in a single ClearCase UCM project context.
> - As of ClearCase versions 8.0.1.8 and 8.0.0.15, CMI be configured for ClearQuest, Rational Team Concert, and Jira.

And:

> **CMI was designed to accommodate the realities of a loosely coupled integration**.
>   The older UCM-CCLC integration, in particular, created the illusion that ClearCase and ClearQuest were tightly coupled. However, separate transactions--one for ClearCase and one for ClearQuest--are required to complete an integrated operation, which means that the operations may only partially succeed and leave ClearCase and ClearQuest data in inconsistent states. CMI logs partial failures and supports replaying failed operations to restore consistency.

In the chart of that article, you can see:

> **Supports record creation from ClearCase**: not supported in CMI.
>   The local client integration enables you to use the `cleartool mkactivity` command to create a new ClearQuest record.